# How to check if array of object's properties are empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, boolean

I'm trying to make a validation in js to check if array of objects' properties are empty strings or not, to clarify more, i have an array that has objects inside, and i want to check for each object if it has an empty property (""), here is the code i've written but i'm not sure this is the correct way

```
const items = [
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
];

const validation = items.map((item) => {
  return Boolean(item.name && item.quantity && item.unit);
});
```

But it is just giving me an array like this:

```
[true, true, true]
```

It is like i want it to only give me the value true if all of the properties are not empty

Thanks

Comment: If you want to verify all entries without hardcoding property names then: `const validation = items.every(i => Object.values(i).every(v => v));`

Comment: @AmirPopovich that works thanks man

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The **`every()`** method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

and get `true` if all values are not falsy.

```js
const items = [
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
];

const validation = items.every(item => item.name && item.quantity && item.unit);

console.log(validation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code **validation** will give **true** if array doesn't contain empty object else it will give **false**.

**you shouldn't compare each property of object , instead compare object length  each time**

```js
const items = [
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
  { name: "something", quantity: "25", unit: "d" },
];
let validation=true;

for(let i=0;i<items.lenght;++i){
   if(Object.keys(items[i]).length===0) {
   validation =false;
   break;
}
}

console.log(validation);
```