# How to check if an array only contains empty strings for a specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array that contains a key `values` which in it has a key called `name`. Example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 277,
        "name": "Kleur",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 789,
                "name": "ivoor",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "id": 793,
                "name": "wit",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "id": 794,
                "name": "zwart",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 278,
        "name": "Cup",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 790,
                "name": "",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 279,
        "name": "Maat",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 791,
                "name": "ONE",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 280,
        "name": "Prothesehoesje",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 792,
                "name": "",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I loop through this and want to check for every loop if the values only contains an empty string as `name` value.

Above desired output should be:

```
false
true
false
true
```

My loop that produces above array:

```
options.forEach(function (option) {
    
    const values = getAvailableValues(option, variants, selected, currentOption);

    values.forEach(function (value, index) {
        console.log(value, index);
    });

    console.log(values.every(name => name === ''));
    
}
```

As you can see I tried this part that I found online: `values.every(name => name === '')` however this returns false for every array as you can see:

[image]

I also found the `some()` method to achieve this, but this only checks an entire array for empty strings while I only want to check for the specific key `name`.

How to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if array of object's properties are empty in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61415297/how-to-check-if-array-of-objects-properties-are-empty-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`every` provides you with an item of the array as argument, you need to access its `name` property:

```
 console.log(values.every(v => v.name === ''));
```

Comment: Thanks this works but what does the `v` stand for? I don't have v in my array

Comment: added to answer..

Answer (score 1):

Map all the entries.

Check if `.some()` of the values have a name that is not an empty string.

Return false if there's a name, true if there is't by reversing the output of `.some()`.

The same can obviously be done with `.every()` by reversing the logic.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 277,
        "name": "Kleur",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 789,
                "name": "ivoor",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "id": 793,
                "name": "wit",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "id": 794,
                "name": "zwart",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 278,
        "name": "Cup",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 790,
                "name": "",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 279,
        "name": "Maat",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 791,
                "name": "ONE",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 280,
        "name": "Prothesehoesje",
        "order": null,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 792,
                "name": "",
                "images": [],
                "order": null,
                "disabled": true
            }
        ]
    }
];
//  Map all the entries
//  Check if .some() of the values have a name that is not an empty string
//  Return false if there's a name, true if there is't by flipping the result of .some()
const mapping = data.map(function( entry ) {
  return !entry.values.some( value => !!value.name ) 
});

console.log( mapping );
```